Can an exponentially growing population perform eugenics and selective breeding at short time scales?
I have the Propagation Hivemind, an all-female human hivemind. She has a superpower called the Dao of Propagation. Basically, it allows her to have children really quickly. When she(the hive members) get impregnated, the Dao  temporally condenses 9 months of baby development into 22 minutes. After the 22 minutes is up and the baby is born, the Dao temporally accelerates the baby to rapidly grow into a 22 year old in the course of another 22 minutes. The Propagation Hivemind has an ideal limit of 22 babies per woman with a cooldown of 2 minutes per each birth. To complement this, The Dao also maintains her at a constant state of peak health and satiation by magically sending sustenance and nutrients inside her, effectively removing her need to eat or be concerned with nutrition.
After reading an article explaining how Michael Phelps, a top athlete swimmer, had the perfect body for swimming, I gained the cool idea of the Propagation Hivemind being able to practically weaponize evolution because of her capacity for exponential growth. Essentially, I want her to perform mass, systemic eugenics and selective breeding on herself to adapt to whatever situation she encounters. For example, I imagine her bunching up a specific subset of herself that are genetically stronger than average and breeding them until she creates a caste of women specialized in physical labor. If she needs to occupy the desert, she can just selectively breed her a group that are extremely heat tolerant. Genetic caste systems, immediate adaptations to different environments, etc. Evolution of this scale usually take a long time but her Dao should offer a shortcut.
Some other worldbuilding details that could be relevant:

She gets her sperm cells from an effective, perfected form of stem cell-to-sperm cell conversion tech courtesy of the Scientocratic Hivemind.
The setting is an alternate, modern day Earth. The Equilibrium Hivemind is deliberately suppressing technological advancement to our current, modern era with only a few exceptions. It forbids the other hiveminds from modifying themselves or evolving away from the human species to an extreme extent.
The hivemind's connected nature and Dao are fundamentally magic but not anything else. Treat the hivemind humans as indistinguishable from normal ones. This includes the Propagation Hivemind and her Dao.
The Propagation Hivemind is in a constant state of danger from the other hiveminds which is why she needs this eugenics route quickly.

My question is: Would this work?

Your system literally runs on magic. If a baby can gestate and mature in just 22 minutes each, all biological bets are off. If you "want her to perform mass, systemic eugenics and selective breeding on herself to adapt to whatever situation she encounters" what makes you think you cannot just let her do that?

By the way, all population change is exponential (growth or decline - barring catastrophe), yours is just faster than ours.

with roughly an hour turnover per generation you are still looking at months for any significant change.

Would it work? Probably she'll get a small effect, once. Then the founder effect will kick in.
Selective breeding works by throwing away all the allele you don't want, and once you've lost an allele, it's exceedingly unlikely to come back on its own. If her sperm have to come from her bodies, population interbreeding to recover lost alleles isn't an option.
Fortunately, there is a solution! If she doesn't care about the wellbeing of any individual body (and, if she's a eugenicist, that's probably the case), she can try mutation breeding. She can dose her bodies (specifically, reproductive organs – she wants heritable mutations) with sufficiently-( but not excessively-)potent mutagens, or hang around in a recent nuclear exclusion zone, and get an abundance of new alleles.
In most cases, this will have no obvious effect. In many cases, she'll get a deleterious effect – maybe a known genetic disease, or maybe an exciting new one. But in the precious few cases, she'll get something useful: brown eyes, longer legs part #17, tetrachromacy. An ordinary eugenics campaign can distribute these alleles throughout the gene pool as needed.
Watch out for mitochrondrial mutations. Mitochondria reproduce asexually, so unless she's really sure she's got a mitochondrial improvement, it's probably safest for the mutant populations to keep their eggs to themselves. Asexual eugenics is playing on hard mode, and mitochondrial diseases are not fun.

A better strategy would probably be training, and maybe epigenetics. The things you list (adaptation to hot climates, manual labour ability) can be developed by individuals during the course of their lifetimes, sometimes in as few as two weeks. Humans do have some population-level evolutionary adaptations (e.g. spleen size), but they're few.
To my knowledge, nobody's ever successfully run a eugenics campaign on humans, and that's not for lack of trying. (About as close as we've managed to get is genocide, which is more about destroying cultures than population groups, and – to my knowledge – has always left humanity worse-off.) The Propagation Hivemind's self-selection plan is not, in my opinion, sensible. But whoever said characters always have to make the sensible decision?

It must logically be possible to run a successful eugenics campaign on humans, since humans are animals, and we have several thousands of examples of successful animal eugenics programs.
The reason why human eugenics do not work so well IRL is that humans breed very slowly, and do not optimize genetically as fast as culturally, so it is pretty moot/inefficient to try. But in OP's scenario, it might work quite well.

Eugenics (if done wisely) does not eliminate an allele from the genepool, but makes it very scarce.  As a hive mind, she can be sure to keep some genebags around to be able to dip into if the need arises.

@GoingDurden Humans have also had probably-severe population bottlenecks, in the not-too-distant past. I doubt we have enough genetic diversity to breed a Great Dane / Chihuahua dichotomy.

Yes but it does not matter
If your hivemind entity can create full grown humans in under an hour it obviously can create resources out of thin air or at least magically transfer them to its bodies. Considering this, I don't see how it would have the need to biologically adapt to anything at all, it will just fill up earth with bodies until either there is no space left, it loses interest in doing so, or any resources it might need for that (if it does at all) are used up.

This seems like an unmarked frame challenge.

Should hit a wall on Phosphorus before anything else stops it.

Whether she can get any real variance at all from simple breeding depends on what genepool the hivemind has access to in order to breed from. Humans have very low genetic diversity, very low; I've heard and read on more than one occasion that there is more genetic diversity in a single chimpanzee troop (~10 individuals) than there is across the entire human race. This gets worse if you leave Africa, the other quote about our genetic diversity is that first cousins in Sub-Saharan Africa share less genetic material than any two Indo-Europeans.
The available breeding rate is high enough though to run a turbocharged multi-generational line breeding experiment, or in fact many of them. If I were in the Hivemind's situation I would run a large number of parallel experiments while keeping a large "baseline" population until such time as I was very sure that I had a successful, stable, and sustainable outcome.
